# Infinite loop p

Tags: javascript, html

what i want to achieve is this:
When is set a desired temperature(its supposed to be  a winecoller simulator) i want that the current temperature rises or lowers to the desired temperature. (-0.2 or + 0.2 degrees every 5 minutes). 
I tried to do a while loop but for some reason it ends in an infinite loop.

**JS**

```
var temperatuur = 7.2;

function openDedeur() {
    temperatuur = temperatuur + 0.9;
    document.getElementById("huidigetemperatuur").value = temperatuur.toFixed(1);
    console.log("U hebt de wijnkoeler geopend, de temperatuur stijgt nu met 0.9º.");

}

function countDown() {
    setInterval(function() {
        temperatuur = temperatuur - 0.2;
        document.getElementById("huidigetemperatuur").value = temperatuur.toFixed(1);
    }, 300000);
}

function test() {
    temperatuur = temperatuur - 0.2;
    console.log("De huidige temperatuur: " + temperatuur);
    document.getElementById("huidigetemperatuur").value = temperatuur.toFixed(1);
    console.log("De motor van de wijnkoeler begint te draaien en zal geleidelijk aan dalen naar de gewenste temperatuur");
    console.log("U heeft als temp:" + handmatigeTemp + " graden ingevoerd.");
}

function zetTemperatuur() {
    var handmatigeTemp = document.getElementById("gewenstetemperatuur").value;
    while (handmatigeTemp < temperatuur) {
        window.setTimeout(test, 3000);
    }
}

while (handmatigeTemp > temperatuur) {
    console.log("De motor van de wijnkoeler begint te draaien en zal geleidelijk aan stijgen naar de gewenste temperatuur");
    console.log("U heeft als temp:" + handmatigeTemp + " graden ingevoerd.");
    temperatuur = temperatuur + 0.2;
    console.log("De huidige temperatuur: " + temperatuur);
    document.getElementById("huidigetemperatuur").value = temperatuur.toFixed(1);
}

if (handmatigeTemp === temperatuur) {
    console.log("Uw Wijnkoeler is op de juiste temperatuur, namelijk " + temperatuur);
}

countDown();
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" onclick= "openDedeur();">Open de deur</button>
<br> </br>
<input id ="huidigetemperatuur" type = "text" name="Huidige temperatuur" value="7.2"/>
<p>De huidige temperatuur</p>
<input id ="gewenstetemperatuur" type = "text" name="Gewenste temperatuur"/>
<p> Uw gewenste temperatuur</p>
<button type="button" onclick="zetTemperatuur();"> Zet gewenste temperatuur</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an interval

```
setInterval(function(){
    // Code
}, 1000*60*5); // 5 min
```

#### Edit

The while loop will cause the browser to run out of memory far sooner than the interval runs for the first time. You could move the code you have in the `while` loop to inside of the `setInterval` callback. It's only interesting to run the check after the temperature has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setInterval, by changing

```
while (handmatigeTemp < temperatuur) {
  window.setTimeout(test, 3000);
}
```

Into

```
var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
   if (handmatigTemp < temperatuur) {
      test();
   } else {
      clearInterval(myInterval); // stop the temperature decrease.
   }

}, 3000);
```

As an alternative, you could use `setTimeout` with a function that calls itself after 3 seconds to recheck your conditions:

```
function setToDesiredTemperature(temp) {
   if (temperatuur > temp) {
     temperatuur -= 0.2;
     setTimeout(function() {
       setToDesiredTemperature(temp);
     }, 3000); // Check again in 3 seconds.
   }
}
```